# System-wide zprofile under macOS

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm used to configure `https_proxy` and other environment variables in `/etc/zprofile`, but that file seems to be overwritten, at least after macOS updates. So is there an other system-wide configuration location which is safe to use?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to do this “system-wide” instead of just for your own user?

Comment: I'll suggest that you read the output from the following command- `man zsh | less -p 'STARTUP'`

Comment: Or read it online at https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html

Comment: It's a server system with multiple users, thus I prefer a system-wide setting. I know the files listed in the man page. The question is, which of these aren't replaced on macOS updates?